# Pandas Groupby remove row where specific value combination occurs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

As Stated, I would like to remove a specific row based on group by logic.  In the below dataframe wherever combination for F and G occurs for an ID, I would like to remove row with value G.

```
import pandas as pd
op_d = {'ID': [1,1,2,2,3,4],'Value':['F','G','K','G','H','G']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=op_d)
df
```

In this case, I would like to remove second row with value 'G' for ID = 1. So far

```
temp = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: (x['Value'].nunique()>1)).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Expected_Output'})
temp = temp.loc[temp['Expected_Output']==True]
multiple_options = df.loc[df['ID'].isin(temp['ID'])]
```

So far, I am able to figure out where each ID has a multiple value. Could you tell how to remove this specific row ?

Comment: can a group also have more elements apart from F and G?

Comment: it could have but my main concern is if it is has F and G and then remove G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Series.eq` + `Series.groupby` transform with `any`:

```
m1, m2 = df['Value'].eq('F'), df['Value'].eq('G')
m = m2 & m1.groupby(df['ID']).transform('any') & m2.groupby(df['ID']).transform('any')
df1 = df[~m]
```

Result:

```
print(df1)
   ID Value
0   1     F
2   2     K
3   2     G
4   3     H
5   4     G
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `isin`:

```
c = (df['Value'].isin(['F','G']).groupby(df['ID']).transform('sum').eq(2) 
     & df['Value'].eq('G'))
out = df[~c].copy()
```

---

```
   ID Value
0   1     F
2   1     H
3   2     K
4   2     G
5   3     H
6   4     G
```